# responsive file in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i want to create a responsive ui which can be used on mobile ,tab and desktop/laptop

I want a responsive ui file which has the dimension for the mobile , tab, and desktop and it has to be in a single file and can be called in the place of mediaquery

Answer (score 0):

Start with the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/responsive/adaptive-responsive), and keep this in mind:

- *Never* change fontsize based on width (hint: do webpages or desktop apps do that?  No!).
- Use `LayoutBuilder` to select breakpoints (2 column vs 3, bottom nav vs side nav).
- Use `Flex` widgets (`Row`/`Column`) to manage layout (using `Expanded`/`Flexible`/`Spacer`).

EDIT: Still a bit experimental, but consider [Flutter Adaptive Scaffold](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_adaptive_scaffold), a first-party (written by Google) package to implement the layout recommendations from the Material team.  It has some breakpoints built-in, and manages things like side vs bottom navigation.

Comment: i know all this things and have done it but for some cases it is not working thats why i want the file